Openvpn stopped working, no logs
I live in Crimea. I used the same configuration of OpenVPN for last 4 years or so.
I used this script to install OpenVPN:
https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install
2 days ago it mysteriously stopped working. My client can connect to VPN server, but when I ping 8.8.8.8 while connected to it, all packets are lost.
Here is tail -f /var/log/syslog output when I connect and try pinging anything:
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> Re-using SSL/TLS context
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1156 EF:94 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1450 EF:121 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1549,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher AES-128-GCM,auth [null-digest],keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1549,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher AES-128-GCM,auth [null-digest],keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]<SERVER_IP>, sid=f0fe61af ab705f83
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=cn_ZEa1Gfis95ePD3Y4
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=<CLIENT_ID>
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> peer info: IV_VER=2.4.7
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> peer info: IV_PLAT=linux
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> peer info: IV_PROTO=2
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> peer info: IV_NCP=2
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> peer info: IV_LZ4=1
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> peer info: IV_LZ4v2=1
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> peer info: IV_LZO=1
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> peer info: IV_COMP_STUB=1
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> peer info: IV_COMP_STUBv2=1
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> peer info: IV_TCPNL=1
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, peer certificate: 256 bit EC, curve prime256v1, signature: ecdsa-with-SHA256
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <SERVER_IP> [<CLIENT_ID>] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]<SERVER_IP>
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: MULTI: new connection by client '<CLIENT_ID>' will cause previous active sessions by this client to be dropped.  Remember to use the --duplicate-cn option if you want multiple clients using the same certificate or username to concurrently connect.
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.2, IPv6=(Not enabled)
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: MULTI: Learn: 10.8.0.2 -> <CLIENT_ID>/<SERVER_IP>
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: MULTI: primary virtual IP for <CLIENT_ID>/<SERVER_IP>: 10.8.0.2
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-GCM' initialized with 128 bit key
Aug 22 23:23:17 VPS ovpn-server[676]: Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-GCM' initialized with 128 bit key
Aug 22 23:23:19 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <CLIENT_ID>/<SERVER_IP> PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Aug 22 23:23:19 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <CLIENT_ID>/<SERVER_IP> SENT CONTROL [<CLIENT_ID>]: 'PUSH_REPLY,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0,peer-id 1,cipher AES-128-GCM' (status=1)
Aug 22 23:23:19 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <CLIENT_ID>/<SERVER_IP> PID_ERR replay-window backtrack occurred [1] [SSL-0] [0_00] 0:4 0:3 t=1724368999[0] r=[0,64,15,1,1] sl=[60,4,64,528]
Aug 22 23:23:19 VPS ovpn-server[676]: <CLIENT_ID>/<SERVER_IP> MULTI: bad source address from client [<CLIENT_IP>], packet dropped
Aug 22 23:23:19 VPS ovpn-server[676]: message repeated 3 times: [ <CLIENT_ID>/<SERVER_IP> MULTI: bad source address from client [<CLIENT_IP>], packet dropped]

/etc/openvpn/server.conf:
port 57373
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server server_ip 255.255.255.0
float
duplicate-cn
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 94.140.14.14"
push "dhcp-option DNS 94.140.15.15"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_stuff.crt
key server_stuff.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3

I called my ISP, and they claim they didn't block anything. Also, shareware VPN providers like SetupVPN and hoxxcom still work, so I doubt it's the government doing it. What else can I do to diagnose or fix this problem?

Looks like underlying link is unstable, and client's IP address changes frequently. float option might help to continue the authenticated connection running (instead of reestablishing) even if the client's IP address changed; for that, you have to specify it in the server config. Also, if this happens "in cycle" (e.g. every two minutes it reconnects), check this answer.

I added float and duplicate-cn just in case into server.conf, because this vpn is used by multiple computers. It still doesn't work.
No, it doesn't happen in cycle. Sometimes it just randomly agrees to work, and works normally for a few hours. Then I turn it off, and upon reconnection it doesn't work anymore.

The clue is in PID_ERR replay-window backtrack occurred which is suggesting that packets from the client are arriving wildly out of order.
The most obvious way to avoid this is to:

Fix at the source (potentially a bad intervening hop that is slow).
Increase the replay window beyond 64 (the default) using the replay-window option (see man openvpn). This lowers the security of the link a bit.
Switch to TCP.

Due to the out-of-order nature of this problem you should anticipate that the flow to the VPN will go pretty slow to compensate for the packet re-ordering.
The blurb for this option in the  man page is pretty large, it ends with this:

The problem is easily fixed by simply using TCP as the VPN transport layer.

So I'd consider that my first solution in your position.

You need to first find out if the OpenVPN service is running on the server. You can use the following command:
systemctl status openvpn

If it's not running or if it's showing inactive, you can start it using this command:
systemctl start openvpn

In case the Openvpn script you're using is deprecated, you could consider reinstalling it in a few steps

OpenVPN service is running on the server. If it wasn't, I wouldn't be able to connect to it.

Some packets may drop or arrive out of order during the lifetime of your VPN connection, so the error message you see is not necessarily the cause of your problem.

My client can connect to VPN server, but when I ping 8.8.8.8 while
connected to it, all packets are lost.

I suggest that you check your routing table before and after connecting to the VPN. Your routing table should change once the connection is established. Feel free to edit your post with this additional info.
To display your routing table on Linux:
route -n

And you can also use this command to find out the path followed to reach a given IP address based on your current routing setup:
ip route get 8.8.8.8

I assume it should be 10.8.0.1, that is the VPN address.
Another thing you could do is log in to the server over SSH, without VPN and check on the server itself if ping 8.8.8.8 works. If it does, then the most likely issue could be lack of IP forwarding, or a routing issue on the client. A firewall too.
